# Powershell handle JSON Response of rest API (drives me crazy)

Tags: json, powershell, api, rest

i am using a rest API and get a JSON as response.

```
{
  "price": 0,
  "price_currency": "EUR",
  "balance": {
    "API Decode": 19
  },
  "decode": [
    {
      "label": "VIN",
      "value": "VSSZZZ7NZGV714632"
    },
    {
      "label": "Make",
      "value": "Seat"
    },
    {
      "label": "Manufacturer",
      "value": "Sociedad Espanola De Automoviles"
    },
    {
      "label": "Plant Country",
      "value": "Spain"
    },
    {
      "label": "Manufacturer Address",
      "value": "De Turismo S.A. (SEAT), Autovia A II  KM 585, 08760 Martorell  Barcelona"
    },
    {
      "label": "Model",
      "value": "Alhambra"
    },
    {
      "label": "Check Digit",
      "value": "Z"
    },
    {
      "label": "Sequential Number",
      "value": "714632"
    },
    {
      "label": "Product Type",
      "value": "Passenger car"
    },
    {
      "label": "Model Year",
      "value": 2016
    },
    {
      "label": "Body",
      "value": "Wagon"
    },
    {
      "label": "Number of Doors",
      "value": 5
    },
    {
      "label": "Number of Axles",
      "value": 2
    },
    {
      "label": "Length (mm)",
      "value": 4854
    },
    {
      "label": "Width (mm)",
      "value": 1904
    },
    {
      "label": "Height (mm)",
      "value": 1698
    },
    {
      "label": "Track Front (mm)",
      "value": 1571
    },
    {
      "label": "Track Rear (mm)",
      "value": 1617
    },
    {
      "label": "Wheelbase (mm)",
      "value": 2920
    },
    {
      "label": "Wheel Size",
      "value": "205/60 R16 96H"
    },
    {
      "label": "Fuel Type - Primary",
      "value": "Diesel"
    },
    {
      "label": "Engine Displacement (ccm)",
      "value": 1968
    },
    {
      "label": "Transmission",
      "value": "Manual/Standard"
    },
    {
      "label": "Number of Gears",
      "value": 6
    },
    {
      "label": "ABS",
      "value": 1
    },
    {
      "label": "Emission Standard",
      "value": "Euro 6"
    },
    {
      "label": "Permitted trailer load without brakes (kg)",
      "value": 750
    },
    {
      "label": "Permitted trailer load with brakes 12% (kg)",
      "value": 2200
    },
    {
      "label": "Permitted towbar download (kg)",
      "value": 100
    },
    {
      "label": "Wheelbase Array (mm)",
      "value": [
        2920
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "Wheel Size Array",
      "value": [
        "205/60 R16 96H"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to access the value of the label VIN, Make and so on by its name.
I can not use the Index because the return JSON is different each time.
Is there a way in powershell how i can access labels like "Emission Standard" by name and use it as a parameter?

Comment: Something like this `($json |ConvertFrom-Json).decode.Where({$_.label -eq 'VIN'}).value`?

Comment: yes.. exactly like this.. thank you:)

Comment: please avoid putting real or sensitive data in your examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hinted in the comments, you can parse JSON into structured objects with [the `ConvertFrom-Json` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7.1):

```
# Read json from file
$json = Get-Content .\path\to\input.json

# Parse using ConvertFrom-Json
$data = $json |ConvertFrom-Json

# Now we can filter by name:
$VINValue = $data.decode.Where({$_.label -eq 'VIN'}).value
```